# Vue3 - Ref in component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs3, ref

I'm making input component for my login form instead of creating input tag every time that I need it. However, I want to save the input value at @input event, thing that's I've made before (when I didn't have component) thanks to refs (by writing ref.value.value)

But now, I can't just add ref on my input because they'are component and not an html tag. How can I fix it ? :( I need their value for regExp test

there's before / after of my input

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozHs3.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No6Sj.png)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way (I used Vue3 Composition API + script setup):

Check out the playground I have set up [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqFUstuwjAQ/BXLQgpIxLlHgFq1vffUS91DIBswih+yN2lRlH/v2qEUgdTevDOzs2OvB/7onOg74CVfIWjXVggbaVZPVjvW59rW0K4l16fnCivRKGhryVlBEhJtfToxJs0wsGsNG0fiiytHKsPOK4csAHaOEKWd9cgG5qFhI2u81SyjKNmFSiEmXBSxiEmJlmZnTcDzRLaODvMhBknDS5YFqwEPyuyzpTTjImaZpm/4kk/uua6cOAZr6OqpV56JIHnJEhIxmhhryQ+ILpRFEZpdjHEMwvp9QSfhO4NKg4Cg8623nwE8GUtOoy8eBYE9+NyDqcGD/8vzRnrnG23peUe6ys+j3K5PGddh1OHJAe0P4QunxodEETQDrXCeda6mnjIt+q1q6X2XbAY9GBRY+T2g6CO6mLrLVMQPcdFHIv6Cf7ZdQ6MMvHrrwvw9uxr3QduZyBcKFMn7SFHzu8HxG2xO8/A=)!

Parent component:

```html
<template>
<Comp v-model="myData.field" />

<br />
  
{{ myData.field }}
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'

const myData = ref({
  field: 'something',
})
</script>
```

Custom input child component:

```html
<template>
<input
  type="text"
  @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  :value="modelValue"
/>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
```

Related docs:

- https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html
- https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#emits

Comment: Hi ! Big thanks for your help. However, I have difficulties to understand this line : 

```@input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)```

Why there's two parameters ?

Comment: The first parameter is to tell to Vue which emit has to be triggered (will search the name in your `defineEmits`). The second one is the actual data to emit.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the ref as a prop and in the input tag put ref.

```js
<InputComponent refProp="email" />



<input :ref="refProp" >
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help :) But how can I manipulate ref's component in the parent ?