# Vue: Pass function into parent component

Tags: function, vue.js, properties, parent

Okay, I'm new to Vue and trying to simplify my problem as much as I can do.
I have two components: NewsItem, NewsItemList

NewsItem:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>A title</h1>
    <a @click="aFunctionDeclaredInThisComponent">Link</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

NewsItemList:

```
<template>
  <NewsItem />
  <div>A mystic box</div>
</template>
```

I want to show/hide the mystic box in `NewsItemList`, if the function `aFunctionDeclaredInThisComponent` is activated, which is in `NewsItem`. I would like to toggle show/hide with a active state in CSS.

My problem is, I don't know how to pass the function into the parent component. Please note, that I use `<script setup>`.

Thank you!

Comment: You may pass function to a child component as a prop communication with the parent can be established using emits or interoperate with store.something, alter store prop in a child and watch at the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but I wrote you a minimal example of how to send data from child component to parent component. Check it out [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

The idea is to emit an event from the child and listen to it in the parent. Don't mind the naming I used, just try to understand how I'm interacting with the data in parent component via child one and try to implement it into your code:

Parent:

```html
<template>
  <Comp @my-var="callback" />
   
  <p
    v-text="`Clicked hide from child? ${test}`"
  />
  
  <div v-show="! test">
    I'm the parent div
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'
const test = ref(false)

const callback = data => test.value = data
</script>
```

Child:

```html
<template>
<button
  v-text="'click to hide parent div'"
  @click="doEmit()"
/>
</template>

<script setup>
const emits = defineEmits(['myVar'])

const doEmit = () => emits('myVar', true)
</script>
```

Comment: In this line you are defining the emits. i did put `myVar` cuz i was wrtiting the example kinda fast, but here, you should properly name the emits you are emitting. i recommend you to read this https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html so you can understand how to name and use them

Comment: you can also check this other answer, which is pretty similar - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74098533/14569750

Comment: @mikasa mark the answer as accepted if solved your issue